# How can I add Java Template Project in Xcode 4?

Tags: java, xcode, templates, project

I wanna know how can I add Java Template Project in Xcode 4.
I'm working with Eclipse and it's really fine but i want to write Java program in Xcode.
Thanks for helping. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is not a first class citizen of Xcode anymore, so you should in my opinion stay with Eclipse.

Comment: Yeah I know, But I think it can be done by writing a simple java project(i.e Hello World!) and add it as a template to Xcode. Is it possible? Thanks for reply by the way.

Comment: Anything is possible given enough time and elbow grease.  Making an IDE work with something it doesn't support out of the box is in my experience not worth the time and effort.   The easiest may be downloading an old version of XCode and just use it.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this question is 6 years old, but I have a similar problem and found what seems an easy solution. I have an old Java project (2008-9) which I maintain but has been dormant. As I prefer to keep it into Xcode I transferred the whole project (sources, project files and all paraphernalia) to a new development machine running el Capitan with Xcode 7.3.1. I opened the project (which was still in 3.1 version) with it, and tried to build it. It failed as Ant was missing. So I downloaded Ant (version 1.10.1) and copied its bin and lib directories under /usr/local/ant, then I changed the project external build tool configuration (under project, go to Info, and you'll see that parameter) which was set to /usr/bin/ant and set it to /usr/local/ant/bin/ant or wherever you put it. Build again and this time it worked.